# Does strand and io objects (like tcp::socket) need to worry about the lifetime of the associating io_service?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

The constructor of `io_service::strand` and io objects like `tcp::socket` take a reference of an `io_service` object. What if `io_service` object destructs before the `io_service::strand`, `tcp::socket` constructed with its reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `io_service::~io_service()` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html) specifically describes this scenario and how to solve it

> **Remarks**
>
> The destruction sequence described above permits programs to simplify
>   their resource management by using `shared_ptr<>`. Where an object's
>   lifetime is tied to the lifetime of a connection (or some other
>   sequence of asynchronous operations), a `shared_ptr` to the object would
>   be bound into the handlers for all asynchronous operations associated
>   with it. This works as follows:
>
> When a single connection ends, all associated asynchronous operations
>   complete. The corresponding handler objects are destroyed, and all
>   shared_ptr references to the objects are destroyed. To shut down the
>   whole program, the io_service function `stop()` is called to terminate
>   any `run()` calls as soon as possible. The `io_service` destructor defined
>   above destroys all handlers, causing all `shared_ptr` references to all
>   connection objects to be destroyed.

Comment: Guess that as long as the destruction of `io_service` happens after all the threads running `io_service.run()` have been joined, I will be fine. Is that corrent?

Comment: @updogliu yes, that's implied here. The `io_service` object's lifetime needs to exist until `run()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Its UB.

I got segfaults when my `io_service` user class was destroyed after `io_service` itself.

Comment: Does calling `io_service.close()` before destruction help?

Comment: @updogliu no, io_service must be destroyed last. Destuctors of any dependent object may want to remove their handlers from `io_service`, so it would crash because the service is no longer exists (and reference points to "trash memory")

Comment: Wow! Then `io_service` really should be reference counted.

Comment: @updogliu i recommend you to spend time for core C++ learning, only after this use the boost::asio

Comment: Why? Is it a stupid idea that let dependent objects take shared ownership to the `io_service` object (or its internal `io_service_impl` object)?

Comment: @updogliu If the I/O objects shared ownership of the `io_service`, then to prevent a cyclic reference, one would have to guarantee that no handlers in the `io_service` have direct or indirect shared ownership of I/O objects.  In essence, it would make using the `enable_shared_from_this` idiom very difficult to get right.

Answer (score 0):

The case you describe leads to crash. io_service is obligatory since io_service performs real threaded execution of the related async calls for sockets, timers and your own code. In order to protect your code from such a disaster please add io_service::work to your io_service right after the creation. After you don't need the io_service anymore - stop the work and io_service.